# Conversion of xml data into string in servlets

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets

I tried to convert xml output to string my code is below:

```
OAuthRequest request2 = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET,"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(first-name,last-name,email-address)");
  request2.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+accesstok);
  Response response2 = request2.send();



  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


  DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc = builder.parse(response2.getBody());
  StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(); 
  Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(); 
  transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(stringWriter)); 
  String strFileContent = stringWriter.toString(); //This is string data of xml file
  System.out.println(strFileContent);
```

i am getting the output as below:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<person>
<first-name>xxxxxxx</first-name>
<last-name>xxxx</last-name>
<email-address>xxxxxxxxxx</email-address>
</person>
```

how do i extract first-name

Comment: doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("first-name").item(0).getFirstChild().getValue()
Text inside any element node is a child of that node

Comment: Thank You, problem resolved. i am able to extract